What is Maru's story?
Well, most of us Devapi and Maru will restore the Surya and Chandra dynasty, after Kalki avatar. I know Devapi's story before he went into Kalapagrama. But, what is Maru's story? Does any scripture mention his past before he went into Kalapagrama?
